# local storage on the stack

Tags: c, assembly, stack, local-storage

I have learned that there are some common cases of local storage on the stack

**case 1**: There are not enough registers to hold all of the local data

**case 2**: The address operator '&' is applied to a local variable, and hence we must be able to generate an address for it

**case 3**: Some of the local variables are arrays of structures and hence must be accessed by array or structure reference.

In the practice problem there are some codes

```
long call_proc()
{
 long x1=1; int x2= 2;
 short x3=3; char x4=4;
 proc(x1,&x1,x2,&x2,x3,&x3,x4,&x4);
 return (x1+x2)*(x3-x4);
}

<generated assembly code>

call_proc:
subq $32, %rsp
movq $1, 24(%rsp)
movl $2, 20(%rsp)
movw $3, 18(%rsp)
movb $4, 17(%rsp)
leaq 17(%rsp), %rax
movq %rax, 8(%rsp)
movl $4, (%rsp)
leaq 18(%rsp), %r9
movl $3, %r8d
leaq 20(%rsp), %rcx
movl $2, %edx
leaq 24(%rsp), %rsi
movl $1, %edi
call proc
.....
```

Q1. In this practice, Is it applied case2 not case1 according to that kind of cases?

Q2. If it is correct case2, Can I get some examples about case1?

Q3. By assuming that code I think it is not necessary for all local variable to be saved in stack like x1, x2, x3, x4. Is it reasonable assuming?

Comment: I don't understand question 3. In the example shown, the variables x1, x2, x3, and x4 must be stored in memory, because their addresses are taken and passed to another function. But I think you already understand this, so I am confused by the question.

Comment: `volatile int foo = 0;` is another way to force the compiler to spill a variable to memory instead of using a register, if you're interested in forcing the code-gen to do something while looking at the compiler output.

Comment: @Peter, the standard doesn’t require that volatile automatic variables be stored in memory instead of registers. (It’s a common misconception.) But every compiler I have looked at does it anyway.

Comment: @prl: I was talking about existing mainstream x86-64 compilers, not a hypothetical deathstation 9000 compiler that implements the ISO C++ standard is the least useful way possible, and isn't usable for low-level systems programming.  But yeah, interesting point, in a function with no non-inline function calls, sure you could say that a register is the permanent location of an automatic variable and have `volatile` just make sure that register always holds the variable's value in the C++ abstract machine.

Comment: @Peter, you don’t need those constraints. In the example in my answer, the local variables live in registers. Adding volatile shouldn’t change the code generated at all. (But it does.)

Comment: @prl: If there were non-inline function calls, they might save/restore the call-preserved register being used for `volatile int x`.  That would amount to inventing reads / writes to a `volatile` object, which is disallowed because that's considered a visible side-effect (the whole point of `volatile`).  Anyway, in mainstream compilers, `volatile` objects always have a memory address.  There is no `register volatile`, except for GNU C *global* register variables (which changes the ABI for any callback functions).

Comment: Do not edit a question that has already received answers, *especially* if it invalidates an answer.  I have rolled back your edit for you.

Answer (score 1):

Q1. Yes, the example shown is case 2.

Q2. To create an example of case 1, simply create a function with more than 6 local variables (for x86-64; for other architectures a different number would be needed), where the values of those variables need to be retained across another function call.

Here is a quick example I wrote: https://godbolt.org/z/S8m0lG. In this example, the variable `n` is the one that the compiler chose to put on the stack, because there isn't a register available to store it. Note that even though this is a trivial example, I made sure to give all variables distinct values, so the compiler wouldn't combine them.

Comment: I have seen your example. Is your example saying n is the one stored in stack since all callee saved register are 6 and not enough for n?(I guess **%rbx: b, %epb: a, %r12d: c, %r13d: d, %r14d: e, %r15d: i** am i right?    )                                                                      
                                                                                                                                      
 In the post of Q3, what if some local variable are not corrupted after calling a function? Even though that situation, Is local variable stored in stack?